# Error when adding a new comment to RTK Query blog post Next.js MockAPI

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, rtk-query

I'm new to Next js and RTK Query, so I don't quite understand how it works. I have an array of objects in mockAPI, I pass through the mutation function an id, by which I find the desired post to which I need to add a new comment, and the object itself containing the information of the new comment, but adding a comment doesn't happen, the array doesn't change in any way.

Here is how it looks like:

```
export const singleApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'singleApi',
    tagTypes: ['Item'],
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://654619eafe036a2fa9552b93.mockapi.io/test/' }),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
     newComment: build.mutation({
            query: ({ newData, id }) => ({
              url: `${id}`,
                method: 'PUT',
                body: (data: any) => {
                      data.comments.push(newData);
                      return data
                },
            }),
        })
    })
})

export const {useNewCommentMutation } = singleApi;
```

Through the endpoint id I access the selected blog object, where there is an array of comments to which I need to add a new object:

```json
{
"title":"New tittle1",
"mainText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facere alias magnam iusto sapiente culpa voluptatum repellat est tenetur dolorem quibusdam modi quaerat, eum optio libero natus doloremque quasi labore soluta!",
"date":"08.11.23",
"likes":0,
"comments":[],
"id":"9"
}
```

This is what my function I use to add a comment looks like. I pass an object with a new comment and id through mutate

```
 const [mutate] = useNewCommentMutation();
 const newCommentPost = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newComent = {
      text: text,
      name: session?.user?.name,
      role: session?.user?.role,
      image: session?.user?.image,
      id: String(data.comments.length + 1),
    };

    if (text.length > 0) {
      try {
       const t =  await mutate({newData: newComent,  id: id });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  };
```

I should end up with a new object in the comments array.

```json
{
"title":"New tittle1",
"mainText":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Facere alias magnam iusto sapiente culpa voluptatum repellat est tenetur dolorem quibusdam modi quaerat, eum optio libero natus doloremque quasi labore soluta!",
"date":"08.11.23",
"likes":0,
"comments":[
{
  text: 'new text',
      name: "John",
      role: "user",
      image: "image",
      id: 2,
}
],
"id":"9"
}
```